# Como mostrar datos correctamente usando php desde un archivo .js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

**Hola Amigos tengo el siguiente codigo:**

```
// Infobox Output
        function locationData(locationURL, locationImg, locationTitle, locationAddress, locationRating, locationRatingCounter) {
            return ('' +
                '<a href="' + locationURL + '" class="listing-img-container">' +
                '<div class="infoBox-close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>' +
                '<img src="' + locationImg + '" alt="">' +

                '<div class="listing-item-content">' +
                '<h3>' + locationTitle + '</h3>' +
                '<span>' + locationAddress + '</span>' +
                '</div>' +

                '</a>' +

                '<div class="listing-content">' +
                '<div class="listing-title">' +
                '<div class="' + infoBox_ratingType + '" data-rating="' + locationRating + '"><div class="rating-counter">(' + locationRatingCounter + ' reviews)</div></div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>')
        }
```

este codigo lo utilizo para mostrar al hacer click una ventana pop up en mi mapa google.

**el siguiente codigo:**

```
// Locations
        var locations = [
            [locationData('page1.html', '../../assets/images/listing-item-01.jpg', "Tom's Restaurant", '964 School Street, New York', '3.5', '12'), 18.4681399, -69.9339234, 1, '<i class="im im-icon-Chef-Hat"></i>'],
            [locationData('page1.html', '../../assets/images/listing-item-02.jpg', 'Sticky Band', 'Bishop Avenue, New York', '5.0', '23'), 18.4813367, -69.9056478, 2, '<i class="im im-icon-Electric-Guitar"></i>'],
            [locationData('page1.html', '../../assets/images/listing-item-03.jpg', 'Hotel Govendor', '778 Country Street, New York', '2.0', '17'), 18.5137181, -69.8791685, 3, '<i class="im im-icon-Home-2"></i>'],
            [locationData('page1.html', '../../assets/images/listing-item-04.jpg', 'Burger House', '2726 Shinn Street, New York', '5.0', '31'), 18.5169269, -69.8744688, 4, '<i class="im im-icon-Hamburger"></i>'],
            [locationData('page1.html', '../../assets/images/listing-item-05.jpg', 'Airport', '1512 Duncan Avenue, New York', '3.5', '46'), 18.5235546, -69.8672669, 5, '<i class="im im-icon-Plane"></i>'],
            [locationData('page1.html', '../../assets/images/listing-item-06.jpg', 'Think Coffee', '215 Terry Lane, New York', '4.5', '15'), 18.5296664, -69.8633336, 6, '<i class="im im-icon-Coffee"></i>'],
            [locationData('page1.html', '../../assets/images/listing-item-04.jpg', 'Burger House', '2726 Shinn Street, New York', '5.0', '31'), 18.8288595, -70.2976137, 7, '<i class="im im-icon-Hamburger"></i>'],
            [locationData('page1.html', '../../assets/images/listing-item-04.jpg', 'Burger House', '2726 Shinn Street, New York', '5.0', '31'), 18.5235546, -69.8791685, 7, '<i class="im im-icon-Hamburger"></i>'],
            [locationData('page1.html', '../../assets/images/listing-item-04.jpg', 'Burger House', '2726 Shinn Street, New York', '5.0', '31'), 18.4681399, -70.2976137, 7, '<i class="im im-icon-Hamburger"></i>'],
        ];
```

lo utilizo para mostrar las dierentes localidades en el mapa.

**He utilizado este codigo pero no me muestra nada**

```
var locations = new XMLHttpRequest();
    locations.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("map").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    locations.open("GET", "locations.php", true);
```

para el archivo "locations.php" he realizado un echo para testear ,pero no he obtenido el resultado

```
 echo "
        [locationData('page1.html', '../../assets/images/listing-item-01.jpg', 'Tom's Restaurant', '964 School Street, New York', '3.5', '12'), 18.4681399, -69.9339234, 1, '<i class='im im-icon-Chef-Hat'></i>'],
        [locationData('page1.html', '../../assets/images/listing-item-02.jpg', 'Sticky Band', 'Bishop Avenue, New York', '5.0', '23'), 18.4813367, -69.9056478, 2, '<i class='im im-icon-Electric-Guitar'></i>'],
        [locationData('page1.html', '../../assets/images/listing-item-03.jpg', 'Hotel Govendor', '778 Country Street, New York', '2.0', '17'), 18.5137181, -69.8791685, 3, '<i class='im im-icon-Home-2'></i>'],
        [locationData('page1.html', '../../assets/images/listing-item-04.jpg', 'Burger House', '2726 Shinn Street, New York', '5.0', '31'), 18.5169269, -69.8744688, 4, '<i class='im im-icon-Hamburger'></i>'],
        [locationData('page1.html', '../../assets/images/listing-item-05.jpg', 'Airport', '1512 Duncan Avenue, New York', '3.5', '46'), 18.5235546, -69.8672669, 5, '<i class='im im-icon-Plane'></i>'],
        [locationData('page1.html', '../../assets/images/listing-item-06.jpg', 'Think Coffee', '215 Terry Lane, New York', '4.5', '15'), 18.5296664, -69.8633336, 6, '<i class='im im-icon-Coffee'></i>'],
        [locationData('page1.html', '../../assets/images/listing-item-04.jpg', 'Burger House', '2726 Shinn Street, New York', '5.0', '31'), 18.8288595, -70.2976137, 7, '<i class='im im-icon-Hamburger'></i>'],
        [locationData('page1.html', '../../assets/images/listing-item-04.jpg', 'Burger House', '2726 Shinn Street, New York', '5.0', '31'), 18.5235546, -69.8791685, 7, '<i class='im im-icon-Hamburger'></i>'],
        [locationData('page1.html', '../../assets/images/listing-item-04.jpg', 'Burger House', '2726 Shinn Street, New York', '5.0', '31'), 18.4681399, -70.2976137, 7, '<i class='im im-icon-Hamburger'></i>']";
```

Alguna sugerencia?

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Porque necesitas php si ya tienes el array en javascript?

Comment: por que quiero buscarlo desde mi base de datos y este array es solo un ejemplo, y realmente no se como hacerlo desde javascript

Answer (score 0):

Si no me equivoco necesitas enviar los datos al servidor, recomiendo uses un llamado ajax https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Aunque para esto te recomiendo uses jQuery como librería http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Entonces a tu php le podrás enviar tu array por POST o GET como de un clásico formulario PHP se tratara.

Cualquier duda puedes consultar.

Saludos

Comment: Hola @jonathan Schell , gracias por tu guia ,modifique la publicacion para ver si estoy en lo correcto con la guia que me suministras

Comment: Hola, si ese es tú código final del ejemplo, te está faltando hacer el send de locations, luego de "locations.open("GET", "locations.php", true);" debes de hacer "locations.send();". Pruebas y me cuentas

Comment: Y sugiero que en un principio evites enviar la data al mapa e intentes imprimir un console.log para ver si al menos el ajax está funcionando bien, osea en lugar de "document.getElementById("map").innerHTML = this.responseText;" solo imprime "console.log(this.responseText)"